# Giving read() a start position

Tags: c, node.js, file

When you give read a start position - does it slow down read()? Does it have to read everything before the position to find the text it's looking for?

In other words, we have two different read commands,

```
read(fd,1000,2000)
read(fd,50000,51000)
```

where we give it two arguments:

```
read(file descriptor, start, end)
```

is there a way to implement read so that the two commands take the same amount of computing time?

Comment: Why did you tag this `c`?

Comment: Cause I might implement it in C if I have to idk

Answer (score 1):

You don't name a specific file system implementation or one specific language library so I will comment in general.

In general, a file interface will be built directly on top of the OS level file interface.  In the OS level interface for most types of drives, data can be read in sectors with random access.  The drive can seek to the start of a particular sector (without reading data) and can then read that sector without reading any of the data before it in the file.  Because data is typically read in chunks by sector, if the data you request doesn't perfectly align on a sector boundary, it's possible the OS will read the entire sector containing the first byte you requested, but it won't be a lot and won't make a meaningful difference in performance as once the read/write head is positioned correctly, a sector is typically read in one DMA transfer.

Disk access times to read a given set of bytes for a spinning hard drive are not entirely predictable so it's not possible to design a function that will take exactly the same time no matter which bytes you're reading.  This is because there's OS level caching, disk controller level caching and a difference in seek time for the read/write head depending upon what the read/write head was doing beforehand.  If there are any other processes or services running on your system (which there always are) some of them may also be using the disk and contending for disk access too.  In addition, depending upon how your files were written and how many bytes you're reading and how well your files are optimized, all the bytes you read may or may not be in one long readable sequence.  It's possible the drive head may have to read some bytes, then seek to a new position on the disk and then read some more.  All of that is not entirely predictable.

Oh, and some of this is different if it's a different type of drive (like an SSD) since there's no drive head to seek.

> When you give read a start position - does it slow down read()?

No.  The OS reads the directory entry to find out where the file is located on the disk, then calculates where on the disk your desired read should be, seeks to that position on the disk and starts reading.

> Does it have to read everything before the position to find the text it's looking for?

No.  Since it reads sectors at a time, it may read a few bytes before what you requested (whatever is before it in the sector), but sectors are not huge (often 8K) and are typically read in one fell swoop using DMA so that extra part of the sector before your desired data is not likely noticeable.

> Is there a way to implement read so that the two commands take the same amount of computing time?

So no, not really.  Disk reads, even of identical number of bytes vary a bit depending upon the situation and what else might be happening on the computer and what else might be cached already by the OS or the drive itself.

If you share what problem you're really trying to solve, we could probably suggest alternate approaches rather than relying on a given disk read taking an exact amount of time.

Answer (score 0):

Well, filesystems usually split the data in a file in even-sized blocks. In most file systems the allocated blocks are organized in trees with high branching factor so it is effectively the same time to find the the **nth** data block than the first data block of the file, computing-wise.

The only general exception to this rule is the brain-damaged floppy disk file system [FAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_Allocation_Table) from Microsoft that should have become extinct in 1980s, because in it the blocks of the file are organized in a singly-linked list so to find the nth block you need to scan through n items in the list. Of course decent operating systems then have all sorts of tricks to address the shortcomings here.

---

Then the next thing is that your reads should touch the same number of **blocks** or **operating system memory pages**. Usually operating system pages are 4K nowadays and disk blocks something like 4k too so having every count being a multiple of 4096, 8192 or 16384 is better design than to have decimal even numbers.

i.e.

```
read(fd, 4096, 8192)
read(fd, 50 * 4096, 51 * 4096)
```

---

While it does not affect the **computing time** in a multiprocessing system, the type of media affects a lot: in magnetic disks the heads need to move around to find the new read position, and the disk must have spun to be in the reading position whereas SSDs have identical random access timings regardless of where on disk the data is positioned. And additionally the operating system might cache frequently accessed locations or expect that the block that is read after N would be N + 1 and hence such order be faster. But most of the time you wouldn't care.

---

Finally: perhaps instead of `read` you should consider using memory mapped I/O for random accesses!

Comment: Yeah I am separating data every 50 bytes, instead of every 4096 bytes, I will test the difference

Comment: It might not show as a large number at 50 bytes but if you've got like 4000 bytes then it is almost always spanning 2 blocks and using 4096 might reduce times spent rather significantly

Comment: does that differ for 32bit vs 64 bit OS?

Comment: No. Not at all.

Answer (score -1):

Read typically reads data from the given file descriptor into a buffer. The amount of data it reads is from start (arg2) - end (arg3). More generically put the amount of data read can be found with (end-start). So if you have the following reads

```
read(fd1, 0xffff, 0xffffffff)
```

and

```
read(fd2, 0xf, 0xff)
```

the second read will be quicker because the end (0xff) - the start (0xf) is less than the first reads end (0xffffffff) - start (0xffff). AKA less bytes are being read.

Comment: This does not even begin to start to address the question asked.